# I wrote a code segment which supposed to work like an bubble sorting algorithm but it doesn't like "1" string

Tags: python-3.x

I've been studying in Hackerrank. Question wants me to sort an given array. I know there is some library functions for those but since i don't know any yet, i've tried to write it manually.

Sample input:

```
15 43 3 2 150
```

Sample output:

```
150 2 3 43 15
```

I've wanted to write a code starts reading the string from the right and stops when it finds a blank. Than adds the string before the blank to the final result. Then keeps going untill it reaches to the [0].

Here's my code:

```
sortedResult = ""
tempNumbers = ""
tempCount = 0
numbers = input()

for counter in range(len(numbers) - 1, -1, -1): 
    if counter != 0:
        if numbers[counter] in range(-1, 11):
            tempCount += 1
            continue
        else:
            for counter2 in range(counter, counter + tempCount + 1):
                tempNumbers += numbers[counter2]
            sortedResult += tempNumbers
            tempNumbers = ""
            tempCount = 0
    else:
        for counter3 in range(counter, counter + tempCount + 1):
                sortedResult += numbers[counter3]

print(sortedResult)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my final code. It is working and it works as the way i intented it to.

```
sortedResult = ""
tempNumbers = ""
tempCount = 0
numbers = input()
firstTenNumbers= "0123456789"

for counter in range(len(numbers) - 1, -1, -1):
    if counter != 0:    
        if numbers[counter] in firstTenNumbers:
            tempCount += 1
            continue
        else:
            sortedResult += numbers[slice(counter + 1, tempCount + counter + 1)] + " "
            tempCount = 0
    else:
        sortedResult += numbers[slice(tempCount + 1)]
        tempCount = 0

print(sortedResult)
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be sorting a string, not a list of numbers. To fix this, change the input line to `numbers = [int(x) for x in input().split(" ")]`. In addition, you should change `tempNumbers` and `sortedResult` to lists and use `.append()` instead of `+=`.

Final code:

```py
sortedResult = []
tempNumbers = []
tempCount = 0
numbers = [int(c) for c in input().split(" ")]

for counter in range(len(numbers) - 1, -1, -1):
    if counter != 0:
        if numbers[counter] in range(-1, 11):
            tempCount += 1
            continue
        else:
            for counter2 in range(counter, counter + tempCount + 1):
                tempNumbers.append(numbers[counter2])
            sortedResult += tempNumbers
            tempNumbers = []
            tempCount = 0
    else:
        for counter3 in range(counter, counter + tempCount + 1):
            sortedResult.append(numbers[counter3])

print(sortedResult)
```

Comment: With this, it works the way i intended it to work. I don't know if i'm asking too much but what if i didn't wanted to work with lists? Beside that i can not find the logical error in my code.

Comment: How would you sort a space-separated list of strings without converting to a list?

Comment: I would start with a "for Loop" counting backwards. It increases a temporary variable by one for everytime the digit of the string is a number. I've tried to count how long every number is. When the digit is a blank, there is another "for Loop" that counts normally, starting from the digit number of that blank digit. Second loop adds every digit (starting from the blank one) to the end result.